# Using an IORef versus using Control.Monad.Trans.Control

Tags: haskell, immutability, monad-transformers, ioref

I wanted to be able to examine the chain of redirects that my application was seeing when making a request via `Network.HTTP.Client`.

That functionality is not built into `Network.HTTP.Client`, though there are some [references to the idea in the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.3.7.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client-Internal.html#g:7), including (non-working) sample code.  It seemed like it could be done mostly reusing almost entirely existing pieces, so I decided to try.

In doing some googling, it sounded like `Control.Monad.Trans.Control` might be able to serve my need to accumulate the requests within a `StateT [Request] IO` stack, however, after a couple of days of unsuccessfully poking around with it, I realized that I could do what I wanted much more easily if I just used an `IORef`---but I'm still curious if I've missed some clever way to do this without resorting to mutability.

My working, `IORef`-based routine looks like:

```
responseOpenWithRedirects :: Request -> Manager -> IO (Response BodyReader, [Request])
responseOpenWithRedirects req man = do
  mWrapIOException man $ do
    requestHistory <- newIORef []
    let
      handleRedirects localReq = do
        res <- httpRaw localReq {redirectCount = 0} man
        modifyIORef' requestHistory (localReq :)
        return (res, getRedirectedRequest localReq (responseHeaders res) (responseCookieJar res) (statusCode (responseStatus res)))
    res <- httpRedirect (redirectCount req) handleRedirects req
    redirectRequests <- readIORef requestHistory
    maybe (return (res, redirectRequests)) throwIO =<< applyCheckStatus (checkStatus req) res
```

My non-working (in that it does not accumulate requests), `Control.Monad.Trans.Control`-based routine looked like:

```
responseOpenWithRedirects :: Request -> Manager -> IO (Response BodyReader, [Request])
responseOpenWithRedirects req man =
  mWrapIOException man $ do
    let
       handleRedirects run localReq = do
         res <- httpRaw localReq {redirectCount = 0} man
         run (modify (\rs -> localReq : rs))
         return (res, getRedirectedRequest localReq (responseHeaders res) (responseCookieJar res) (statusCode (responseStatus res)))
    (res, redirectRequests) <- flip runStateT [] $ liftBaseWith $ \run -> httpRedirect (redirectCount req) (handleRedirects run) req
    maybe (return (res, redirectRequests)) throwIO =<< applyCheckStatus (checkStatus req) res
```

The problem, as I see it, is that I can't return the updated state from the `handleRedirects` function, because that is called from within `httpRedirect`---and as a consequence, I never get the chance to use restoreM on the updated value.  I'm failing to see how I can combine this stuff successfully, but I suspect that's just a failure of imagination or understanding in my part.

To make things as simple as possible, here's a test harness you can use with each version:

```
#!/usr/bin/runghc

import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Data.IORef
import Data.ByteString.Lazy
import Network.HTTP.Client.Internal
import Network.HTTP.Types

main :: IO (Response ByteString, [Request])
main = do
  manager <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
  request <- parseUrl "http://feeds.feedburner.com/oreilly/newbooks"
  withResponseAndRedirects request manager $ \(res, reqs) -> do
    bss <- brConsume $ responseBody res
    return (res { responseBody = fromChunks bss }, reqs)

withResponseAndRedirects :: Request -> Manager -> ((Response BodyReader, [Request]) -> IO a) -> IO a
withResponseAndRedirects req man =
  bracket (responseOpenWithRedirects req man) (responseClose . fst)
```

Comment: I'm afraid `MonadControl` won't help here. In order to use it, the underlying function must be polymorphic (for example like the lifted [bracket](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.3.0/docs/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v:bracket)) so that you can pass additional information from the inside function out. | I really appreciate that you provided a self-contained, working example!

Comment: Oh.  Obviously you must be able to rearrange the pieces of the return value as necessary, which means you can't have a rigid type for that value.  As with so many thing in my experience with Haskell, once you see it, it makes perfect sense.